# sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox do not work properly

Tags: oracle, symfony1, widget

I have a problem with a sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox. It do not save false in the database when the checkbox is unchecked.

In my schame my field is a boolean, and i don't have bug in the value displayed.

Set the default value like this : `$this->setDefault('status', false);` don't work either.

My widget :

```
$this->widgetSchema['SUSPENSION_TEMP'] = new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox();
$this->validatorSchema['SUSPENSION_TEMP'] = new sfValidatorBoolean(array('required' => false));
```

The default :

```
$this->setDefault('SUSPENSION_TEMP', false);
```

Any ideas ?

**Edit:**

It save 1 when the checkbox is checked. And do not change the database value when you unchecked and save. So once you checked once, value is always 1 in database (true for my code).

**Edit2:**

I have two clues to add. If the field is an integer in the schema.xml, both values work, bu we got a poblem on value displayed (checkbox checked qih the 0 value). Here, he field is a boolean.

The setter receive two kinds of value, 'on' when checkbox is checked and true when it's not. I tried to set default value to false in form, and to overide he setter. Both don't work.

I mean the setter work, but for an unknown reason the basic seer is called right after with a wrong value.

**Edit3:**

Ok, i understand part of the problem. The setter is not called, when the checkbox is unchecked. I thought it was because, m code displayed a var_dump(). It was because later i copy the old version of this object in archive purpose.

But symfony should detect that the field has been rendered and it doesn't. I don't know why. I know why in html, but obviously symfony should be able to tell himself  "hey, i add a checkbox here".

Is there an elegant way o do this, or should i checked it by hand ?

Comment: Well, I checked a code from a project and I do nothing more to handle it. The default behavior: is checked the field will be `1` in the db otherwise, `0`. When you define nothing except the widget & validator, it doesn't work?

Comment: No it doesn't. I don't have others options applying on that field. Extra fields are enabled but not filtered. I'm working with oracle. I have a behaviour on models. It handle some fields like created_at, created_by, but don't use or call the problematic field.

Comment: There is a workaround in others project looking like your. But in the view, the checkbox field is built by hand or using a deprecated helper. It's using the value="1". There is no problem with cheking here. In fact, the problem is that when the checkbox is unchecked, symfony send true to the field's setter. But only when the database field's value was already 1. It works perfectly when his values is 0.

Comment: Really strange. I do not have problem with this. You might need to handle it in your model maybe ? Maybe it's a problem with doctrine and oracle.

Comment: I guess i will have to use the weird workaround. I ried to overide my setter, but for an unknown reason the base setter is called right after with the filter value. Undoing the job of my model's setter. That may come from propel. We do not use propel, because my company did a lot of mainenance on client projects with older symfony and propel. Propel is crap with oracle but i'm stuck with it.   So i will use the workaround, seem i don't have any other choices. Thanks for your time have a nice day.

Comment: I have an exemple on another project with the same exact config. he same symfony, ect ....  And i works perfectly even withouth the value="1". So i really don't understand :p.

Comment: Yeah, there are similar. I though i got it when i saw that the working one, was using a char(1) instead of a number(1) (and it remembered me something), but it don't work either.

Comment: I tried with an html checkbox, with the right name and value="1", and i don't know why, the value true is still given to my base setter, when the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from my form handling. My legacy code, did no render all fields (ex : some stamp field, updated by a behavior). It was using fromArray, then save. This update only the fiels rendered.

The traditionnal symfony form, give null to all non-rendered fiels in order to chcuk for required validation.

So you need to check by yourself and set to 0, when you are using a fromArray then save. Still, i find the form->save really dumb, because you need to send useless(in this case) or confidentials data to your client in order to use it.